# How does one access an apache_beam.io.fileio.ReadableFile() object?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use the `apache_beam.io.fileio` module in order to read from a file `lines.txt` and incorporate it into my pipeline.

`lines.txt` has the following contents:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

When I run the following pipeline code:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

     lines = (
         p
         | beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern="lines.txt")
         | beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
     )
     # print file contents to screen
     lines | 'print to screen' >> beam.Map(print)
```

I get the following output:

```
<apache_beam.io.fileio.ReadableFile object at 0x000001A8C6C55F08>
```

I expected

```
line1
line2
line3
```

How can I yield my expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resulting `PCollection` from

```
p
| beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern="lines.txt")
| beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
```

is a `ReadableFile` object. In order to access this object, we can use various functions as documented in the [apache beam pydoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.ReadableFile).

Below we implement `read_utf8()`:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    lines = (
        p
        | beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern="lines.txt")
        | beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
        | beam.Map(lambda file: file.read_utf8())
    )
    # print file contents to screen
    lines | 'print to screen' >> beam.Map(print)
```

and we get our expected result:

```
line1
line2
line3
```